# How to make combobox dependent on filtered table?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have the following table:
[image]

The table can get filtered by a command button / userform:

[image]

```
Sub standardfilter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Tabelle1")
    
    With tbl.Range
        
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Gremienauswahl.ComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(Date), Operator:=xlAnd
        
    End With
    
    Range("Tabelle1").Sort Key1:=Range("D5"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
End Sub
```

Is there a possibility that I can first apply the "Gremium" filter with combobox1 (column 1 has committee values) and then combobox2 shows all the available date values for this specific committee value?

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: I added some code, idk what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this...

```
Sub standardfilter()

    Dim resultsDictionary As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    
    Me.ComboBox2.Clear
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Tabelle1")
    
    With tbl
    
        'clear any pre-existing filters
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            With .AutoFilter
                If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
            End With
        End If
        
        With .Range
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.ComboBox1.Value
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & Date
            .Sort Key1:=.Range("D5"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        End With
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
    End With
    
    Set resultsDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        resultsDictionary(rw.Cells(2).Value) = "" 'second column/Gremientermin
    Next rw
    
    Me.ComboBox2.List = resultsDictionary.keys()
    
End Sub
```